# Are there in AIX mechanisms EPOLL/KQUEUE or their equivalents?

Tags: unix, posix, aix, iocp, kqueue

Are there in AIX mechanisms EPOLL(Linux2.6)/KQUEUE(FreeBSD)/IO Completion Port(Windows) or their equivalents?

And what kind of mechanisms are optimal for AIO on AIX for a large number of network connections?

For example according to the Benchmarks, the mechanisms KQUEUE / EPOLL much faster than SELECT.
http://libevent.org/

Comment: note the relatively small number of followers for `aix` as you rollover your mouse on it. Best to add tags for the programming language you want to use and possibly unix or linux. Good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [poll set](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/p_bostechref/pollset.html) is the best choice today.  There is also the [iocp](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/kernelextension/iocomp_ports_aio.html) interfaces which comes from windows.  And there are the [aio](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/kernelextension/async_io_subroutines.html) interfaces which use iocp under the covers.  But, I believe poll set is the preferred choice of the three if you are using a relatively new version of AIX.

Comment: Thank you! This is very similar to EPOLL of Linux and the interface is close to it. POLLSET appeared only in version 6.1 of AIX? And why, instead IOCP, is the preferred choice the POLLSET, IOCP did not implemented through POLLSET?

Comment: IOCP predates pollset.  IOCP goes fairly far back.  pollset seems a bit more stable and can push more performance according to the performance guys.  I think both are on 5.3.  Here are the 5.3 pubs: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp