# Capturing stdout/stderr separately and simultaneously from child process results in wrong total order (libc/unix)

Tags: c, unix, pipe, posix, libc

I'm writing a library that should execute a program in a child process, capture the output, and make the output available in a line by line (string vector) way. There is one vector for STDOUT, one for STDERR, and one for "STDCOMBINED", i.e. all output in the order it was printed by the program. The child process is connected via two pipes to a parent process. One pipe for STDOUT and one for STDERR. In the parent process I read from the read-ends of the pipes, in the child process I `dup2()`'ed STDOUT/STDERR to the write ends of the pipes.

My problem:
I'd like to capture STDOUT, STDERR, **and "STDCOMBINED" (=both in the order they appeared)**.  But the order in the combined vector is different to the original order.

My approach:
I iterate until both pipes show EOF and the child process exited. At each iteration I read exactly one line (or EOF) from STDOUT and exactly one line (or EOF) from STDERR. This works so far. But when I capture out the lines as they come in the parent process, **the order of STDOUT and STDERR is not the same** as if I execute the program in a shell and look at the output.

Why is this so and how can I fix this? Is this possible at all? I know in the child process I could redirect STDOUT and STDERR both to a single pipe but I need STDOUT and STDERR separately, and "STDCOMBINED".

---

PS: I'm familiar with libc/unix system calls, like `dup2()`, `pipe()`, etc. Therefore I didn't post code. My question is about the general approach and not a coding problem in a specific language. I'm doing it in Rust against the raw libc bindings.

PPS: I made a simple test program, that has a mixup of 5 stdout and 5 stderr messages. That's enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no defined order for emitting stdout and stderr.  They are separate streams.

Comment: Is there any way I can workaround this? e.g. disable the buffer for stdout of the child process?

Comment: As a minimum, the parent would need to `select` or `poll` the pipes to detect when new data is available. You've induced a difference in the order simply by reading *"exactly one line (or EOF) from STDOUT and exactly one line (or EOF) from STDERR."*

Answer (score 3):

> At each iteration I read exactly one line (or EOF) from STDOUT and exactly one line (or EOF) from STDERR.

This is the problem. This will only capture the correct order if that was exactly the order of output in the child process.

You need to capture the asynchronous nature of the beast: make your pipe endpoints nonblocking, `select`* on the pipes, and read whatever data is present, as soon as `select` returns. Then you'll capture the correct order of the output. Of course now you can't be reading "exactly one line": you'll have to read whatever data is available and no more, so that you won't block, and maintain a per-pipe buffer where you append new data, extract any lines that are present, shove the unprocessed output to the beginning, and repeat. You could also use a circular buffer to save a little bit of `memcpy`-ing, but that's probably not very important.

Since you're doing this in Rust, I presume there's already a good asynchronous reaction pattern that you could leverage (I'm spoiled with go, I guess, and project the hopes on the unsuspecting).

*Always prefer platform-specific higher-performance primitives like [`epoll` on Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html), [`/dev/poll` on Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5177/6mbbc4g9n/index.html), [`pollset` &c. on AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17380181/1329652)

Another possibility is to launch the target process with `LD_PRELOAD`, with a dedicated library that it takes over glibc's POSIX `write`, detects writes to the pipes, and encapsulates such writes (and only those) in a packet by prepending it with a header that has an (atomically updated) process-wide incrementing counter stored in it, as well as the size of the write. Such headers can be easily decoded on the other end of the pipe to reorder the writes with a higher chance of success.

Comment: I'll check if I can find a Rust abstraction. But especially for the sake of the learning effect I'd love to do it against libc. I'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: Even this may not work reliably; if the parent is scheduled out for a little while, by the time it gets to run again, the child may have written to both fds.  `select` will tell you that there is data available on both pipes, and there will be no way to know which came first.

Comment: @NateEldredge Shells don't do anything better, do they? Is there any mechanism in linux that allows you to mutually interlock pipe writes so that another process could observe the exact order without strace-ing the process?

Comment: @UnslanderMonica: Not that I know of.  For sockets there is `SO_TIMESTAMP` which lets you see the exact time at which each chunk of data was received, but I'm not aware of any such thing for pipes.

Comment: One solution would be to use a multithreaded reader, with one thread for `stdout` and one thread for `stderr` each reading its stream and when a full line is read writing that to a common stream in a way that ensures no interleaving of data. If the originating process messed up its writing, there's nothing such a reader could do anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is really no different than with `select`, I'd actually wager that in a long benchmark the two-thread approach may not win or be marginally worse in terms of accuracy than `epoll`. Not sure about `select`, but `epoll` really should be the first thing attempted if the system supports it.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica It's quite different - if one of the two hangs for a decent interval because of buffering in the originating process, but the other continues to emit multiple lines of output, then a process using select either has to intermix the continuing output with the stalled output, or wait for the stalled output and emit lines known to be out-of-order.  With two threads, each reading complete lines and emitting them immediately upon receipt, there's no stall on all output when waiting for one to flush.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not possible to strictly do what you want to do.

If you think about how it's done when running a command in an interactive shell, what happens is that both stdout and stderr point to the same file descriptor (the TTY), so the total ordering is correct by means of synchronization against the same file.

To illustrate, imagine what happens if the child process has 2 completely independent threads, one only writing to stderr, and to other only writing to stdout. The total ordering would depend on however the scheduler decided to schedule these threads, and if you wanted to capture that, you'd need to synchronize those threads against something.

And of course, something can write thousands of lines to stdout before writing anything to stderr.

There are 2 ways to relax your requirements into something workable:

1. Have the user pass a flag waiving separate stdout and stderr streams in favor of a correct stdcombined, and then redirect both to a single file descriptor. You might need to change the buffering settings (like [stdbuf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) does) before you execute the process.
2. Assume that stdout and stderr are "reasonably interleaved", an assumption pointed out by @Nate Eldredge, in which case you can use @Unslander Monica's answer.

Comment: I think the "interleaving" was Andrew Henle's suggestion, not mine.

Comment: Hi! This is exactly what I was working on yesterday :) The user has now two strategies to choose in the library function. One is to catch STDOUT/STDERR separately with reasonable accurate ordering. The other is to catch both via the same file descriptor/pipe with the loss of stdout-only or stderr-only lines but the total order is correct. PS: I found out that for (the single threaded child process case) the accuracy is 99% if between each alternating stdout/stderr output the time is >100ms.
I catch stdout/stderr for the "separately" strategy via 2 threads. I store the timestamps for ordering