# UNIX redirections from files for both input and output - that also shows what was the input in the output file

Tags: c, unix, redirect

Sorry if I phrased the question a bit weird.

I'm trying to debug a program, and I'd like to redirect both the input and output from-to files, like this:

`MyProgram.out << MyInput.txt >> MyOutput.txt`

My problem with this is that I also need the output file to contain the input of every function.

For example, let's say that `MyInput.txt` has one line with the number 3, and `MyProgram.out` only asks from the user to input a number.
So what I'll get is:

`Choose a number:`

But what I'd like to get is (written in `MyOutput.txt`):

`Choose a number: 3`

Is there a way to make it show the inputs as well?

Comment: Is using script not an option?

Comment: If there isn't anything built in then it sure is. Thing is, how do I get the input file to be redirected both to the 'input' and 'output' portions? I need it to be as if I'm looking at it through the terminal (user inputs)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible, in the general case, without modifying `MyProgram.out`, as I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65068684/10678955).

You are trying to interleave 2 pipes (input & output) in a synchronized fashion, where the synchronization is defined by `MyProgram.out`.

But pipes are asynchronous: the data (e.g. the line containing `3`) has already been read from the file into the pipe before `MyProgram.out` even started, and now `MyProgram.out` is the one who decides whether to first read from the input pipe, and how many lines/bytes, or write something like `Choose a number:` to the output pipe.

So only `MyProgram.out` knows if `Choose a number:` should be written before `3`, or vice versa.

There are some unclean ways you could still achieve that:

- You could write a program that uses `ptrace(2)` to see if `MyProgram.out` reads the input first or writes the prompt first.
- You could assume that every line of output corresponds to every line of input - which isn't the case in your program because when it writes `Choose a number:` it doesn't add a `\n`.

However, [`script`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/script) only looks at the terminal, and you redirect the output from a file, not the terminal, so using `script` won't help you here.